# Parse value in db with jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

Hello how i can parse my data to database with jquery or php after submit?
Look at my project after user press `+` `modal` pop-up `select` value `checkradio` and on `submit` the `value` printed in `div` i want to send it to database.
[Here is my project](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jmoXed?editors=1010)

Comment: Try with [`ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) script help full for pass the data to php and then create the [`php insert`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj5s4iO_ZTUAhXKqI8KHem1BBgQFggmMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fphp%2Fphp_mysql_insert.asp&usg=AFQjCNFkrFMVj4eqMXQiuxDLU-EXK3DL3Q&sig2=2e0CL162iy1IX4Rqdc97zQ) script for adding the data to dB

Answer (score 0):

You need to submit the data to server first, via AJAX in your case, and let server side script handle the database entry, for further reference these are useful:
[Jquery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)
[Ajax fundamentals](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Use [ajax request](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) and send datas to your php in your function

```
$("#btnsubmit").click(function(){
    // Your code

    $.ajax({
        url: "yourscript.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: datas
    });
});
```